# Wordpress 404 Link

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Hii I want to redirect users if page not found to home_url(404) like this. Is this possible? My goal is some special word like product if found in url then send user to that page and if not contain my url with product then redirect to 404 page. Here is code example

```
$redirect = false;
if( is_404()){
    $url = home_url( $wp->request );
    $path_to_check_for = '/product/';
        if( strpos($url, $path_to_check_for)  !== false ) {
            $redirect = true;
        }
        if($redirect == false){
            header("Location: ".home_url(404));
            exit;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_redirect_404() {
    if(is_404() && strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/product/') === false ) {  
            wp_redirect( home_url(404));
        }
    }


add_action('wp_head', 'custom_redirect_404');
```

**Edited:** If the 410 page contains the string '/product/' it redirects to homepage

Comment: Hii I don't want to redirect home. I want to redirect theme default 404 page in this case.

Comment: Check my edited code

Comment: Hi
I added this part inside of is_404


 `if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/product/') !== true) {
            wp_redirect( home_url(404));
            exit();
        }`
not working it's redirect to home page.

Comment: Ok, try with the new code. 
The condition is now stricter, it works.

Comment: Sorry It's not working. It's again redirect to home.

Comment: This is how it works on my side:
example
website.com/product/page -> redirect to default 404 page
website.com/shop/page -> redirect to homepage

Comment: Found the solution

`if(is_404() && strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/product/') === false ) {  
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
            get_template_part( 404 );
            exit;
        }`

Comment: Yep, that's was the opposite you were asking. ^^
Anyway, glad it works.